# FancyBox в Yandex Maps

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Не могу найти помощи в этом вопросе:

1. Очень хочу сделать так, чтобы картинки внутри текста балуна открывались с помощью fancybox,а так же ссылки на другие страницы
2. Вот ссылка на мой сайт [censored]
3. Вот где работает http://www.reklama.kolpino.ru/outdoor/

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">

   ymaps.ready(init);
   function init() {

       var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
           center: [59.7459, 30.58666],    
           zoom: 15    
       }),     

           myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({    
               geometry: {    
                   type: "Point",    
                   coordinates: [59.7459, 30.58666]    
               },

               properties: {    
                   iconContent: 'Метка',    
                   balloonContent: '<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="http://imperiyakolpino.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/map-icon-small.jpg" > <img src="http://imperiyakolpino.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/map-icon-small.jpg" width="200" /> </a>'    
               }    
           }, {    
               preset: 'twirl#redStretchyIcon'    
           });    

       myGeoObject2 = new ymaps.GeoObject({    
           geometry: {    
               type: "Point",    
               coordinates: [59.744, 30.582]    
           },    
           properties: {    
               iconContent: 'Метка 2',    
               balloonContent: 'Тестовый текст 2'    
           }    
       }, {    
           preset: 'twirl#greenStretchyIcon'    
       });    

       myMap.geoObjects    
           .add(myGeoObject2)    
           .add(myGeoObject);    
   }
   ```

Хотя картинку внизу работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. подключаете fancybox**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bitrix/templates/kors/js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.min.js"></script>

$(function(){
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                openEffect: 'none',
                closeEffect: 'none',
                nextEffect: 'none',
                prevEffect: 'none',
                helpers: {
                    thumbs: {
                        width: 120,
                        height: 80
                    }
                }
            });
            $(".image, .image1").fancybox({});
            //здесь вешаете fancybox на элементы с классом `image`, `image1`
        });
```

**2. подключаете и выводите яндекс карту со всеми элементами**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?lang=ru-RU&load=package.full"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
ymaps.ready(function () {

var sections = 
    [
      {'name':'Магистральные 3x6',
      'placemarkOptions':{
        'iconImageHref':'/upload/iblock/a75/a758b82218b126acaa9616fb14ed5508.png',
        'iconImageSize':['41','42'],
        'iconImageClipRect':[['0','0'],['41','42']],
        'iconImageOffset':['-28','-42'],
        'iconContentOffset':['4','4'],
        'iconContentSize':['33','11'],
        'iconShadow':true,
        'iconShadowImageHref':'/upload/iblock/610/610ab04636440ba60a3f5283475fce7e.png',
        'iconShadowImageSize':['66','34'],'iconShadowImageClipRect':[['0','0'],['66','34']],
        'iconShadowImageOffset':['-28','-34']},
        'hotPlacemarkOptions':{
           'iconImageHref':'/upload/iblock/a75/a758b82218b126acaa9616fb14ed5508.png',
           'iconImageSize':['41','42'],
           'iconImageClipRect':[['82','0'],['123','42']],
           'iconImageOffset':['-28','-42'],
           'iconContentOffset':['4','4'],
           'iconContentSize':['33','11'],
           'iconShadow':true,
           'iconShadowImageHref':'/upload/iblock/610/610ab04636440ba60a3f5283475fce7e.png',
           'iconShadowImageSize':['66','34'],
           'iconShadowImageClipRect':[['132','0'],['198','34']],
           'iconShadowImageOffset':['-28','-34']
        },
        'hiddenPlacemarkOptions':{
           'iconImageHref':'/upload/iblock/a75/a758b82218b126acaa9616fb14ed5508.png',
           'iconImageSize':['41','42'],
           'iconImageClipRect':[['41','0'],['82','42']],
           'iconImageOffset':['-28','-42'],
           'iconContentOffset':['4','4'],
           'iconContentSize':['33','11'],
           'iconShadow':true,
           'iconShadowImageHref':'/upload/iblock/610/610ab04636440ba60a3f5283475fce7e.png',
           'iconShadowImageSize':['66','34'],
           'iconShadowImageClipRect':[['66','0'],['132','34']],
           'iconShadowImageOffset':['-28','-34']
        }
      }
    ];
        var elements = [{
            'id':'34',
            'name':'1',
            'photos':['/upload/iblock/5ae/5ae92a6b878ef354502e16d89d1c2260.jpg','/upload/iblock/2ec/2ecc3d0922512220e152a819be9dc34b.jpg','/upload/iblock/f72/f726ffea4593195f52e143344c38403c.jpg','/upload/iblock/312/312ca3a2fadcf363cac0ef892335f5b0.jpg'],
            'comment':'',
            'sectionId':'0',
            'coordinatesYandex':['59.749823802707','30.559663511044'],
            'coordinatesCustom':['59.749834631069','30.559754706151'],
            'sideA':{'hot':false,'occupied':false},
            'sideB':{'hot':false,'occupied':false}
            }];
}
</script>
<div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 680px;"></div>
```